# Python: Plot array as function of time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, dimensions

I want to plot this exponential function:

`T = np.random.exponential(3,50)` as a function of time (Minutes 1-15) `t = np.arange(0,15,1)`.

I get: `x and y must have same first dimension...`

Could you explain how it can be done properly? I'd like to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is not a function, it's an array. You must ensure that `t` and `T` have the same shape.

You should pass a `size` that is the same as the length of `t` to [`np.random.exponential`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0, 15, 1)
T = np.random.exponential(3, size=len(t))

plt.plot(t, T)
```

*Note that since `T` is random, there is no direct relationship between `t` and `T`.*

Output:

[image]

Conversely, to scape `t` from `T`'s shape, use [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
T = np.random.exponential(3, 50)
t = np.linspace(0, 15, num=len(T))
plt.plot(t, T)
```

Output:

[image: numpy scaling array with linspace to plot]

Comment: thank you. Does that mean that if I have an array with X values, I also need X time/space values? If I had fewer values, would I have to scale?

Comment: @Sylvia you can of course scale two arrays of different size, but how depends on what you're doing exactly. Can you please clarify what is your final goal?

Comment: yes, of course. I would like to plot 50 values as a function of time. max(time) = 15 (min) and min(time) = 0 (min). Presumably I would then have to scale?

Comment: I see, then you can rescale `t` with `linspace` (see update)